# How do I get a plain array back from vuejs with a component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, vue.js, vue-resource

I am using a call to my database to retrieve some results and pushing them onto an array. However when I `console.log(this.activeBeers)` I don't get an array back but instead an object. How can I get a plain array back instead of a object?

```
Vue.component('beers', {
    template: '#beers-template',

    data: function() {
        return {
            activeBeers: []
        }
    },

    ready: function() {
        function getActiveBeers(array, ajax) {
            ajax.get('/getbeers/' + $('input#bar-id').val()).then(function (response) {
                $.each(response.data, function(key, value) {
                    array.push(value.id);
                });
            }, function (response) {
                console.log('error getting beers from the pivot table');
            });

            return array;
        }

        console.log(this.activeBeers = getActiveBeers(this.activeBeers, this.$http));
    },

    props: ['beers']
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is correct, `getActiveBeers` sends an HTTP request and then immediately returns the array, it doesn't wait for the ajax request to come back.  You need to handle the updating of `activeBeers` in the success function of the ajax request.  You can use the `.bind()` function to make sure that `this` in your success function refers to the `Vue` component, that way you can just push the ids directly into your `activeBeers` array.

```
Vue.component('beers', {
    template: '#beers-template',

    data: function() {
        return {
            activeBeers: []
        }
    },

    ready: function() {
        this.getActiveBeers();
    },

    methods: {
        getActiveBeers: function(){

            this.$http.get('/getbeers/' + $('input#bar-id').val()).then(function (response) {

                $.each(response.data, function(key, value) {
                    this.activeBeers.push(value.id);
                }.bind(this));

                console.log(this.activeBeers);

            }.bind(this), function (response) {

                console.log('error getting beers from the pivot table');

            });

        }
    }

    props: ['beers']

});
```

Comment: @Stephan-v Can you post what the value is of `activeBeers` that you're seeing?

Comment: Ah yes, I think Peter's answer explains that issue.  Vue variables are actually objects with a `get` function.  So when you call `this.activeBeers`, it accesses the `get` function and gives you an array.  But the actual variable is an object.  For all intents and purposes, when you use it, it will be an array.

Answer (score 2):

AJAX is done asynchronously so you won't be able to just return the value that you do not have yet.

You should console.log your stuff after the `$.each` to see what you received.

Comment: I am doing that already check the code. The function contain the $.each loop is way before my log of the actual array. Besides that I am still receiving the correct values, except it's an object and not an array.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers pointed out, your `getActiveBeers()` call is returning before the callback that fills the array gets executed.

The reason your array is an object is because Vue wraps/extends arrays in the underlying data so that it can intercept and react to any mutating methods - like push, pop, sort, etc.

You can log `this.activeBeers` at the beginning of your `ready` function to see that it's an object.

By the way, if you want to log the unwrapped/plain array of `activeBeers`, you can use your component's `$log` method:

```
this.$log(this.activeBeers);
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/api/#vm-log
Here is the link to the vm.$log doc. This command reduces the complexity of getting to the data object and expressing it as a plain object.